# How can i subtract duration from time in excel

Tags: excel

imagine that i have a time for example 7:00 AM and also i have a duration for a task for example 12:30 (12 hours and 30 minute). when i subtract 7:00 from 12:30 it gives me ####### that the true answer should be 18:30 PM. what is the solution?

Comment: It should be 19:30 and not PM. PM will be for 12 hour date format means 7:30 PM.

Comment: _It should be 19:30 and not PM..._ Huh? 7:00AM -12hrs = 19:00PM, 19:00PM -30mins = 18:30PM @Harun24HR

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path subtracting the two, but there are additional things you need to consider: A good description is on Microsofts help page if you scroll down to "Subtract" - this gives you a step by step guide and examples.

You can find the guide here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad

Answer (score 1):

Excel cannot display a negative time. This can be solved by adding one day to the initial time.

```
=1+A2-B2
```

[image]